# Getting the product info from different store in checkout process

Tags: product, magento-1.9, orders, cart, onepage-checkout

I have two stores. View one is in English and the other is the translation, each product has the same price and information but the difference is the translation.

I want all orders in the back-end with the same items information taking in to account the fact the site/view that the item was ordered from. For example suppose I have the item with a name of name1 in first view and name2 in the second view. If the customer creates the order in first view I will see it as name1, and name2 if he creates it from the second view.

I tried to find the code that processes the checkout to change the code and set the store id to one in all cases, but I didn't find it.

Then I tried to handle it in shopping cart by changing the code `_initProduct()`in :

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php
From
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
   ->load($productId);
To
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->setStoreId(1)
   ->load($productId);
```

So could you tell me please how I can do both things, changing the info of the product in the cart and order?

**Edit One:**

After tracing Magento code

I changed the method `setProduct` in class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` to have this code:

```
$productTemp=null;
    if($product->getStoreId !== 1){
    $productTemp =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product') ->setStoreId(1)
       ->load($product->getId());
    }
    else
    {
    $productTemp=$product;
    }
    $this->setData('product', $product)
        ->setProductId($productTemp->getId())
        ->setProductType($productTemp->getTypeId())
        ->setSku($this->getProduct()->getSku())
        ->setName($productTemp->getName())
        ->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())
        ->setTaxClassId($productTemp->getTaxClassId())
        ->setBaseCost($productTemp->getCost())
        ->setIsRecurring($productTemp->getIsRecurring());
```

My question is, is it bad practice to edit core files & does this edit have a negative impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the product from different store.

I have to override the `CartController` located in `\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php`

edit the code store in `_initProduct()` to the store you want to load the product from it.

Also I have to edit the quote by editing method `setProduct` in class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`